# How to set up Google TV without remote

Tags: chromecast

I have lost the remote for a Google TV device and after a factory reset I can't connect to it with the Google Home app on my phone. How do I make it work?

Comment: not an IoT question ... questions about the use of entertainment equipment are off topic here ... answers to such questions are also off topic here

Comment: well, it's the top result on google for chromecast problems and also it seems to fit with "consumer technology used for home automation" from https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work with Google Home and Google TV apps entirely.  After I did the same thing... factory reset... no remote.  I was stuck at the same screen of pairing the remote.  If you press the button on the back of the Chromecast... just once... don't hold it down, it goes into a pairing mode.  I then opened the Google TV app and selected the small TV icon in the lower right hand corner.  It showed the Chromecaset as an available device.  I selected it and it connected.  Then, I just mashed the center button and got past the pairing screen.  After that, I just walked through the rest of the startup procedure.  It asked me to repair somewhere in the middle while downloading apps.  Worked!

Comment: I don't think this works unless both the Chromecast and the app on the phone is connected to the same WiFi. So if we are setting up a factory reset device, how could you come past this step?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this to work by connecting a Bluetooth mouse and mashing buttons, including the mouse's back button and middle button. You can connect a bluetooth mouse by pressing the little button on the back of the Google TV -- it will automatically search for and connect to any devices in pairing mode.

Once the mouse connected and I'd mashed buttons, the screen walked me through installing an Android app called "Device Utility" that "activated" the Google TV device, and then I could set it up through Google Home.

Comment: Tried this too, it really does find my bluetooth mouse, however it fails to finally pair with it. So I can't setup the Chromecast w/ Google TV I have.